# "Exception: No data to insert" while importing dataset into Clickhouse under Docker

Tags: csv, docker, clickhouse

I'm trying to play with Clickhouse using [this manual](https://hackernoon.com/clickhouse-an-analytics-database-for-the-21st-century-82d3828f79cc). I've set up [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server). I've also successfully created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tax_bills_nyc
(
    bbl Int64,
    owner_name String,
    address String,
    tax_class String,
    tax_rate String,
    emv Float64,
    tbea Float64,
    bav Float64,
    tba String,
    property_tax String,
    condonumber String,
    condo String,
    insertion_date DateTime MATERIALIZED now()
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY tax_class
ORDER BY owner_name

Ok.
```

I quit Clickhouse client and checked Docker container is up:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
55991995335b        yandex/clickhouse-server   "/entrypoint.sh"    About an hour ago   Up About an hour    8123/tcp, 9000/tcp, 9009/tcp   some-clickhouse-server
```

I try to import sample dataset with the following command:

```
curl -X GET 'http://taxbills.nyc/tax_bills_june15_bbls.csv' | docker run --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server --input_format_allow_errors_num=10 --query="INSERT INTO test_database.tax_bills_nyc FORMAT CSV"
```

And I get the following error:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0  176M    0  2641    0     0   7494      0  6:50:28 --:--:--  6:50:28  7481Code: 108. DB::Exception: No data to insert

  0  176M    0 94321    0     0  35245      0  1:27:16  0:00:02  1:27:14 35233
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

What could be the reason and how to fix that?

Comment: The problem was that docker run was missing -i parameter. This command worked for me: curl -X GET 'http://taxbills.nyc/tax_bills_june15_bbls.csv' | docker run -i --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server --input_format_allow_errors_num=10 --query="INSERT INTO test_database.tax_bills_nyc FORMAT CSV"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused, because `docker run` is used for running (starting not existed) container. I am not sure, that `docker run` is what you suppose to do after successfully check your container is running.

Instead of `docker run` you should use

```
docker exec -i <container-id-or-name>
```

So, your line should be:

```
curl -X GET 'http://taxbills.nyc/tax_bills_june15_bbls.csv' | docker exec -i some-clickhouse-server --query="INSERT INTO test_database.tax_bills_nyc FORMAT CSV"
```

You could always find info about docker commands in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm)